# Can't pin folder to Windows Explorer Jump List

Tags: windows-7, jumplist

I've tried looking for a solution and have yet to come across one. Does anybody know how to pin a folder to the Windows explorer jump list? I've tried dragging the folder on top of the explorer icon and a few others with no success.

P.S. Please don't confuse this with the taskbar... I'm interested specifically in the Windows explorer jump list and not the task bar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured this out... I utilized this tip (http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/6709/add-the-recycle-bin-to-the-taskbar-in-windows-7/) and didnt realize that it replaced all the functionality that the Windows Explorer icon gave... once I removed the recycle bin from my task bar... problem solved!

Comment: You don't need to remove the recycle bin from your taskbar. Just re-order the taskbar items so that the explorer icon is first - left of the recycle bin. Basically, depending on the order, Windows will pin to the recycle bin and refuse to pin to the explorer icon. Once the jump list is updated, you can re-order the icons back again - the folder will stay in the correct jump list.

Answer (score 5):

I'm running Windows 7 professional and I can pin a folder to the explorer jump list by simply dragging it and dropping it on the explorer Icon. You can also pin a folder by opening the jump list clicking the pin button next to the items listed.

Is you explorer icon on the taskbar the original or have you created it yourself? Have you tried re-creating it?

Comment: I'm running Windows 7 enterprise and when I try the drag and drop method I get the red no entry sign...

I have pinned a few things to it from the Frequent list... but not sure how that gets populated.

Answer (score 1):

Via [this thread](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itproui/thread/8e3c2a80-392d-44e2-8b9f-6eb5deb9a1e1)

1. Go here `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations\`
2. Delete `1b4dd67f29cb1962.automaticDestinations-ms`

... this will clear your jump list.

Alternatively, I just deleted all the items in the folder and `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\CustomDestinations` .

Answer (score 1):

Why all of a sudden did my links disappear from my Windows Explorer Jump-up menu?
Why can't I drag shortcuts to my taskbar and see them appear in the Jump-up menu of Windows Explorer any longer?

[Here's the answer](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/w7itproui/thread/77d1df80-0311-4530-ab17-9489975b9fce). This one works.

> This problem should be caused by corrupted user account. Try perform a
>   system restore:
>
> 1. Click the Start Button, type "system restore" (without quotation marks) in the Start Search box and press Enter. Click Continue if
>      necessary.
> 2. Click Choose a different restore point, and click Next.
> 3. Choose a time before the issue occurs and click Next.
> 4. Click Finish and click Yes to confirm the operation.
>
> If the problem still happens, create a new account and to see if the
>   issue persists.
>
> 1. Click the Start button, click Control Panel.
> 2. Under the Classic View, double click "User Accounts".
> 3. Click "Manager another account" and click "Create a new account".
> 4. Input the user name, select "Computer administrator" as the desired account type, and then click "Create Account".
> 5. Restart your computer and log on as the new created user account.

Answer (score 1):

It's 2015 and still I was looking for how to do that. This is the answer I found [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20151130131514/http://geekswithblogs.net/jeremyj/archive/2012/05/17/pinning-any-folder-location-to-the-task-bar-explorer-jump-list.aspx):

> So I discovered how to pin any folder to the Windows Explorer jump list on the Windows 7 task bar. Any entries in the 'Frequent' menu can be pinned using its context menu, but a folder that does not appear in the 'Frequent' menu can still be pinned just by dragging its path from the address bar in the Explorer window onto the task bar icon. The pinned folders can then be accessed by using the context menu of the task bar button.

And it works on Windows 8.1 too.

Same thing as said here on [dummies](https://www.dummies.com/article/technology/computers/operating-systems/windows/windows-10/how-to-pin-a-file-or-folder-to-the-windows-7-taskbar-195307/).

Answer (score 1):

SOLUTION:

1. Find the "Jump List ID" of the program that's giving you issues [here](https://community.malforensics.com/t/list-of-jump-list-ids/158) or anywhere similar (e.g.  Microsoft Office Word 2010 x86 is "a7bd71699cd38d1c")
2. Go to Run (Windows + R), copy this in, press enter:     %appdata%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations
3. Find the file with the Jump List ID from above, and delete it (e.g.  "a7bd71699cd38d1c.automaticDestinations-ms" for Word 2010)

This immediately clears that programs jump list (recently accessed and pinned) but you will now be able to pin once more.

Answer (score 0):

Sorted !!! The exact same thing happened to me. Red no sign when i tried to drag and drop to start button.

I had modified my start orb using Windows 7 Start Button Changer v 2.6. 
When i reset to original orb, it worked fine, tried putting my moded one on, red no sign is back.

So reset to original orb.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

> I'm running Windows 7 enterprise and when I try the drag and drop method I get the red no 
>   entry sign... I have pinned a few things to it from the Frequent list... but not sure how 
>   that gets populated.

Also running Windows 7 Enterprise here. I have had the same problem intermittently and have some solutions that worked for me:

I noticed a 'bug' with the taskbar when both **Windows Explorer** and a **shortcut** were pinned simultaneously. It treats the shortcut as a windows explorer icon, so when I attempt to drag & drop a folder to pin it, it says "Pin to {sortcut_name}" instead of "Pin to Windows Explorer".

Removing the shortcut then repeating the procedure works, until perhaps when (1) that shortcut's properties are edited from within the taskbar by a user. The property change **will not** propagate to the shortcut on disk and windows will treat the shortcut as an Explorer icon.

(1) kind of a guess for now

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to locate the file using the Windows Search.

I just type these commands in the Windows 7 Start Bar textbox, and the files were shown:

shell:Recent\AutomaticDestinations

Shell:Recent\CustomDestinations

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Hinted by a comment in this question i realized it was because I had changed the default location for explorer - by right clicking the explorer icon, then right clicking `windows explorer`, choosing `properties` and editing the shortcut `target` to point directly to a different location - in my case `D:\`.

Repeating the procedure, but pointing to `%WINDIR%\explorer.exe "D:\"` instead solved the problem - while preserving my "special" default location.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the jump list was such a long list and the folder that I was adding were exist in the list before. So when I add the folder it won`t show up.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by dragging the folder in the explorer address bar over to the taskbar but in the bottom right section over the clock.

Answer (score -2):

To my knowledge you can't do this in W7 without external tools. I'm using [7stacks](http://www.alastria.com/index.php?p=software-7s) and it's working very well. Let's you do a bit of other customization too.

Comment: Thanks. I guess I'll check it out... althought I really wish I didnt have to do it that way. :-)

Comment: @CGA I am using Win 7 now and to pin things to a jumplist I can simply drag the folder and drop on the Windows Explorer icon on the taskbar. Its the same for any other apps too, drag a link from IE to the taskbar and it pins it to IEs jumplist, and with songs in WMP. No external tools required.

Comment: This actually is one of the features in Windows 7. Just like Connor, when i go to a folder's parent, and then drag that window to the taskbar Explorer icon, it gives the option to drop it and pin it there. This is without any third party software. If this is not working it may be something futzed on your install, or maybe it is something with the Enterprise edition? I'd suggest finding another Win7 machine (maybe at Best Buy or somewhere) and give this a try to see it in action. It works fine on my install.