# folder won't show up in jumplist

Tags: windows-8, jumplist, pin

I use the jumplist of explorer to pin folders that I use often. I have a folder with all my game shortcuts and on Windows 7 I always had a link to it pinned on the explorer icon. But since moving to Windows 8 it won't show up in the jumplist anymore, so I can't pin it.
I just want easy access to my games folder so I don't have to go back to the desktop every time.

Does anyone know why this could happen? Or maybe a way to programatically alter the pinned items of explorer?

Pinning other folders does work.

Comment: Is this a folder you created?

Comment: Yes, I tried adding explorer and it changed it to "C:\Windows\explorer.exe", but it still won't shop up as pinned or in the jumplist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can drag and drop the folder to the jump list, a tool tip and the "link" drag and drop icon will appear.

Answer (score 1):

Pin the shortcut to the games folder directly to the Taskbar:

1. In Windows Explorer, navigate to the folder that you want to pin to the taskbar.
2. Right click on the folder, click on Send to and Desktop (create shortcut), and close Windows Explorer.
3. On the desktop, right click on the folder shortcut, click on Properties, Shortcut tab, type explorer in front of the Target path of the folder leaving a space inbetween them, and click on Apply.

[image]

change the icon to better identify it, make a rightclick on theshortcut and select `"Pin to Taskbar"`

**Source:**

http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/9305-taskbar-pin-unpin-folder.html

Answer (score 0):

I eventually solved this by adding my folder to the Favorites library. When in the concerning folder, right-click Favorites -> Add current location to Favorites.

I also tried making this folder into a library, but failed there.

Also, I have BetterExplorer en ClassicShell installed, they might be causing some problems.

Answer (score 0):

For future users:
I had the same thing (without upgrading to Win 8) where one specific folder didn't want to be pinned anymore.
After some searching, **I deleted the file of the jumplist [given in this thread](https://superuser.com/questions/68004/cant-pin-folder-to-windows-explorer-jump-list#answer-236992) and manually recreated the whole jump list**. Makes me believe this file was corrupted somehow.

In short:

1. Make a screenshot of your current jumplist
2. Delete `%APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\Recent\AutomaticDestinations\1b4dd67f29cb1962.automaticDestinations-ms` (This will also delete your automatic jump list of course = the ones that you didn't pin and can see below the manually pinned ones which are determined by the times you visit a folder)
3. Recreate them again by dragging them to Explorer Icon on the taskbar